# Ruby redaction not printing

Tags: ruby, each

I am running through the Codecademy lessons to get up to speed with the basics of Ruby but I hit a snag with their redacted! exercise. I posted what I think should do the trick but it refuses to print.

The exercise instructions are as such :

Let's start simple: write an .each loop that goes through words and just prints out each word it finds.

Please help if you can. Thank you! Here is my code :

```
puts "What is your text, bra?"
text = gets.chomp
text.downcase!

puts "What is being hidden?"
redact= gets.chomp
redact.downcase!

words = text.split(" ")
eachredact = redact.split(" ")

#loop through the words in the string
words.each do |x|
    print "#{x}" + " "
  end
```

Comment: Nothing is printing. The error they give me is : Oops, try again! It looks like you didn't print each word from the user's text to the console.

Comment: Do you think it is just my browser or something?

Comment: where you ran the code?

Comment: codecademy.com. It is a website where you can do exercises and learn to code. I was using it for some Ruby basics. The site has coding exercises and a window to the right of the exercise where it shows the output of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran it as below :

```
puts "What is your text, bra?"
text = gets.chomp
text.downcase!

puts "What is being hidden?"
redact= gets.chomp
redact.downcase!

words = text.split(" ")
eachredact = redact.split(" ")

#loop through the words in the string
words.each do |x|
    print "#{x}" + " "
end
```

***Output:***

```
What is your text, bra?
i anm
What is being hidden?
Good
i anm
```

see here:

[image: codeacadamy]

Comment: I am still getting that error but if the code is correct, then I will assume it is just assume that the website is being funky and I'll keep it moving to the next exercise. Based on what the instructions are and the code that I wrote, does it look correct? That is basically what I need to know I guess

Comment: Yea, its odd. Mine prints too but they still give me an error : / Oh well, I'll chalk it up to a glitch and move on to the next exercise. Thanks for taking a moment to help me out though!